# Is a newline character invalid in XML?

Tags: xml

Based on what I found in the XML specification, following 3 characters are the only ones that are illegal:

1. &
2. <
3. >

We are working with a vendor on a tool which does not seem to be able to process a newline character.

e.g.

```
<Comments> This is line 1
This is line 2
</Comments>
```

will produce an error in the tool and the root cause I am being given is that newline character is not allowed in XML. The specification does not clearly say anything about this.

I am trying to understand if newline is indeed an invalid character in XML or if this could be the limitation of the tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you mean to ask about **well-formed, not valid, XML**.  (See [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for details on the difference.)

Newline characters are most certainly allowed in well-formed XML.

- `&#13;` (`#xA`) is CR
- `&#10;` (`#xD`) is LF

(Windows usually end lines with CR+LF; MacOS X and Linux, LF; classic Mac OS, CR.)

The XML Recommendation does indeed clearly allow both.  See [Character Range](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets):

> Char     ::=      #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] |
> [#x10000-#x10FFFF]

### Common Usage

**Within an element, new lines are typically *significant* to an application:**

```
<a>one
two</a>
```

usually means something different than

```
<a>one two</a>
```

**Between markup, new lines typically are *insignificant*:**

```
<a>
   <b>one</b>
</a>
```

usually means the same as

```
<a><b>one</b></a>
```

### Other Characters

Finally, you're painting in somewhat sloppy strokes in saying that `&`, `<`, and `>` are illegal.  Instead, use the following guidelines:

- `&`: must use `&amp;` if not a part of an entity reference.
- `<`: must use `&lt;` if not a part of a tag, comment, PI, etc.
- `>`: must use `&gt;` if part of the string `]]>`.
- `'`: must use `apos;` if within attribute values delimited by `'`.
- `"`: must use `quot;` if within attribute values delimited by `"`.

### See also

- [How to add a newline (line break) in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504890/290085)

Answer (score 0):

No. New line characters are perfectly acceptable in XML. They are included in [the character range for text](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets).