# How to do new line in (I don't know what language)

Tags: xml, text, server, task, line

I don't know what code language, but I want move text to another line.

My code:

```
      <Task Talk=" 0｛Hello, {ff0000}This text to another line, how?..{-}｝" Teleports="-1" YuanBaoComplete="-1" TaskZhangJieID="1" TaskIndexOfZhangJie="0"  />
```

I'm trying put {\n} but don't working.

Comment: Please explain, maybe show, more about how exactly you try `put {\n}`. Maybe then somebody can guess at the programming language.

Comment: Please explain, maybe show, more about how exactly "don't working". How does it fail? What did you expect? What does happen?

Comment: Does not work. After this text I'm converting to myfilebin.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is a data format that gets its meaning from other applications and standards that use it.  Your question cannot be answered with satisfying detail because it does not specify the application or standard that defines what the `Task` element or its `Talk` attribute means.

For an application-independent treatment of how to get newlines to work in XML, see

- [How to add a newline (line break) in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504890/290085)

but be aware that identifying the application or standard associated with the XML is preferable.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I felt there was enough value in my response to justify classifying it as an "answer" to a gracious interpretation of the question asked.  When to downvote, vote to close, comment, or answer is a judgement call.  I am also open to follow-ups and amending my answer.  I hope you see value in the route I took in this case.

Comment: I see some value in there, which does make it an answer. I just stumbled over "I answer this unanswerable question". Won't downvote though. If you are open for proposal "The question cannot be answered with satisfying detail because ... . But generally ..."

Comment: I'm onvert the xml file to myfilebin.txt.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Fair enough.  Answer updated to address your concerns.  Thank you.

Comment: @Ned: Then realize that your question is more about an unspecified conversion program than it is about XML or any of the highly abstract other tags you've used here.  If you're looking for understanding, read my answer and the associated Q/A link.   If you're looking for a quick fix, you can't have one without directing your question specifically to be about the unspecified conversion program itself.