# XML Newsfeed for WordPress - <br/> won't show

Tags: html, xml, wordpress, feed

I'm trying to write an XML-Newsfeed for Wordpress that can be imported through a plugin and then put in to article-section where it can be edited and so on.

This is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE content>

<content>
<article id="1">
    <mainid>
        <![CDATA[DE20201201]]>
    </mainid>
    <titel>
        <![CDATA[Titel]]>
    </titel>
    <picture>
        <![CDATA[https://link.png]]>
    </picture>
    <article-content>
        <![CDATA[TEXT, JUST A LOT OF TEXT<br/> EVEN MORE TEXT]]>
    </article-content>
    <pubdate>2020-12-01 00:00:59</pubdate>
</article>
</content>
```

My Problem is that the "`<br/>`"'s in the element  are not interpreted as an actual new line in the article in Wordpress.

I'm a total noob at this stuff, i know there's stuff like xsl and xslt but I'm not sure how all of that is working.

Comment: Have you tried the escapes \r or \n instead of `<br>`? So you can maybe enforce a line feed / carriage return or a new line

Comment: won't work, the feed has to be in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe have also a look to that [Stack Overflow - How to add a newline (line break) in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504890/how-to-add-a-newline-line-break-in-xml-file)

And use instead of `<br/>`

```
Line Feed LF: "&#xA;"
Carriage Return CR: "&#xD;"
```

Comment: Plus one for the link to the canonical newline / line-break Q/A.  ;-)  Whether this will work will depend upon how the processing application treats the passed-through `&#xA;` and `&#xD;`.

Comment: these old guys will never disappear *lol*

Comment: Lol, my old self or my my old answers?

Comment: Sorry I did not recognize that I share your own answer! I was thinking about the old LF or CR stuff ...

Comment: No problem, you recognized its relevance before I did!

Comment: Hi, thank you, for your input, but this won't work here because the text in <article-content> is stored elsewhere in a data abse and is then put in to the element <article-content> so i can't directly edit the text in the xml-file, and i can't change the text in the data base because it is also use in other stuff where its needs to be html so the <br> is needed. is there some way to replace the <br>through some command?

Comment: @notsure: Now you're asking a coding question without having posted any code.  Put up a [mcve] if you need debugging help.

Comment: Hey guys, thank you all for your help. The problem was solved another way.

Answer (score 0):

`CDATA` is not interpreted as markup, so your `<br/>` is only interpreted as **C**haracter **DATA**.

Change

```
<article-content>
    <![CDATA[TEXT, JUST A LOT OF TEXT<br/> EVEN MORE TEXT]]>
</article-content>
```

to

```
<article-content>
    TEXT, JUST A LOT OF TEXT<br/> EVEN MORE TEXT
</article-content>
```

or

```
<article-content>
    <![CDATA[TEXT, JUST A LOT OF TEXT
EVEN MORE TEXT]]>
</article-content>
```

or

```
<article-content>
    <![CDATA[TEXT, JUST A LOT OF TEXT]]><br/> <![CDATA[EVEN MORE TEXT]]>
</article-content>
```

to have `<br/>` be interpreted as markup.

See also

- [How to add a newline (line break) in XML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35504890/290085)