# line breaks in string resource

Tags: java, android

I have a long text in my string resources containing multiple line breaks.
obviously i don't want to write it all in one line like `<string name="text">This is the first line\nThis is the second line\n...</string>`
But when i do it like this:

```
<string name="text">
    This is the first line\n
    This is the second line\n
    ...
</string>
```

The start of the lines are indented a bit. How can i prevent this?

```
This is the first line
  This is the second line
```

i set the text ´directly in xml with `android:text="@string/text"`

Comment: The indentation causing this error, Removing `tab spaces` will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tabs when parsing ("\t") I think.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is use "" in your text string, such as like this:

```
    <string name="text">
"This is the first line
This is the second line"
    </string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use usually something like this below:

[image]

You can use this also for long texts. You have to write this without tabs or spaces, just from the begin of the line like the photo.

Edited:
"br tag" is used for new line

Comment: the br tags are completly ignored

Comment: Oh, thanks. Yes then you don't have to use them.

Comment: here you can find more information about adding new line in xml files 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35505248/19867158